# Use PowerShell to merge info from two different CSV files into a new file

Tags: powershell

I newbie in powershell. I have two different CSV files, that I am looking to merge together into one using a primary key field from each file. 
An example would be:

**CSV 1:**

```
ID - TB - Number
01:01 - SB - 24
12:04 - DV - 63
```

**CSV 2:**

```
ID - UR1 - UR2
01:01 - soft - install soft
12:04 - soft - uninstall soft
```

**Desired Output**

```
ID - TB - Number - UR1 - UR2
01:01 - SB - 24 - soft - install soft
12:04 - DV - 63 - soft - uninstall soft
```

Comment: This is not a valid csv, your values are separated by `space-space`. Can't you change it to just comma?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed to CSV is not properly formatted, did an ugly fixe (first two lines), after that you can do it as bellow

```
$csv1 = (gc C:\tmp\csv1.ps1 -raw) -replace ' - ',',' | ConvertFrom-Csv
$csv2 = (gc C:\tmp\csv2.ps1 -raw) -replace ' - ',',' | ConvertFrom-Csv

$columns1 = ($csv1 | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty).Name

$csv1 | % { 
    $row1 = $_
    $row2 = $csv2 | ? {$_.ID -eq $row1.ID}
    $row2 | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | % {
        if($_.Name -notin $columns1) { 
            $row1 | Add-Member $_.Name $row2.$($_.Name)
        }
    }    
}

$csv1
```